# .replaceNode(); replacing incorrect nodes

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8

This will be my third time editing and rewriting this question. As I debug the code, I continue to find new facets to the problem. I will try to organize this post to be a bit pain free to read...

A. When attempting to replace `<object>` nodes with an `<iframe>` via a For loop, the loop will replace the first instance of an "object" node, then stop. All content afterwards goes missing.

B. While trying to isolate the issue, noticed if I try to replace `<object>` nodes with a different tag, such as `<p>` or `<button>`, the tags will encompass neighboring elements.

Here is a sample of the for loop in question; you may notice that it's end goal is to find and replace any YouTube `<object>` nodes it locates with YouTube `<iframe>` equivalents. However currently, I am using a dummy element, in this case a button, to try to illustrate the issue.

```
article.content = items[n].querySelector("description").textContent;
            //Test to parse the article content into HTML. 
            var HTMLParser = new DOMParser();
            var htmlArticleContent = HTMLParser.parseFromString(article.content, "text/html");
            //Test Video Script Editor 
            var objectPoll = htmlArticleContent.getElementsByTagName("object");
            var numberOfObjects = objectPoll.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < numberOfObjects; j += 1) {
                if (objectPoll[j] != null) {
                    var videoEmbed = htmlArticleContent.getElementsByTagName("embed")[j];
                    if (videoEmbed != null) {
                        var videoSrc = videoEmbed.getAttribute("src");
                        if (videoSrc.split(".")[1] == "youtube") {

                            var newSrc = videoSrc.replace("/v/", "/embed/");
                            var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
                            iFrame.setAttribute("src", newSrc);
                            iFrame.setAttribute("height", objectPoll[j].getAttribute("height"));
                            iFrame.setAttribute("width", objectPoll[j].getAttribute("width"));
                            iFrame.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
                            iFrame.setAttribute("allowfullscreen");
                            iFrame.setAttribute("type", "text/html");
                            iFrame.setAttribute("iv_load_policy", "3");
                            var test = document.createElement("button");
                            objectPoll[j].replaceNode(test);
                        }
                        else { }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Instead, here is the end result, from the DOM Explorer:

```
<button>
<br>
<br>
<font size="3"><b>WoW Stream 2</b></font><br>
<br>
<object width="682" height="416" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=wow_2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#000000">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="allowNetworking" value="all"><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=wow_2&amp;auto_play=player&amp;start_volume=25"></object>
</button>
```

Somehow, `replaceNode()` is encasing entirely incorrect segments of HTML. I am concerned that the object locations are being indexed incorrectly via `getElementsByTagName()`.

Here is a small sample of the original HTML, which is being fed from an external site via WinJS.xhr; I understand if it is a pain to read through. I isolated the first three object tags and separated them by line breaks.

```
    <img src="http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2011/november/d3.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:0px; vertical-align:bottom" /> 
    <b><a href="http://www.diablofans.com/news/1413-uber-bosses-speed-kill-video-blue-posts-bonus-blizzard-comic-contest-entry-black-ops-2-outsells-harry-potter-and-star-wars/" target="_blank">Uber Bosses Speed Kill Video, Blue Posts, Bonus Blizzard Comic Contest Entry, Black Ops 2 Outsells Harry Potter and Star Wars</a></b><br /> <br />
    <font size="3"><b>Battle.net World Championship</b></font><br /> <br /> 
    <div style="text-align: center;"><font size="3"><b>WoW Main</b></font><br /> <br /> 

    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="416" width="682" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=wow" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=wow&amp;auto_play=false&amp;start_volume=25" />
</object>

    <br /> <br /> <font size="3"><b>WoW Stream 2</b></font><br /> <br /> 

    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="416" width="682" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=wow_2" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=wow_2&amp;auto_play=player&amp;start_volume=25" />
</object>

    </div><br /> <br /> <font size="3"><b>Patch 5.1 - Loss of Control Alerts</b></font><br /> Patch 5.1 adds alerts when you lose control of your character to the default UI. They tell you what is affecting your character and the remaining duration. <br /> <br /> 
    <div style="text-align: center;">

    <object width="853" height="480"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/PbIAuqwFC-Q?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/PbIAuqwFC-Q?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="853" height="480" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>

    <br /> <br /> 
    <a href="http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2012/november/alertOptions.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2012/november/thumb/alertOptions.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a> <a href="http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2012/november/alerts.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2012/november/thumb/alerts.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a> </div><br /> <br /> <font size="3"><b>Popular Glyphs</b></font><br /> Guildox recently added a new feature that will show you which glyphs are popular with the top 5% of players, broken down by PvP and PvE. If you are looking for the <a href="http://www.guildox.com/go/g.asp?c=8&amp;r=&amp;w=&amp;a=24&amp;n=&amp;e=pve" target="_blank">popular glyphs</a> for your class, this should help!<br /> <br /> <div style="text-align: center;">
```

Comment: can you show the structure of your html?

Comment: When are you calling this code? Are you waiting for DOM load?

Comment: This code is editing HTML from a parsed string of HTML embedded inside two XML tags. 

This is the source: http://www.mmo-champion.com/external.php?do=rss&type=newcontent&sectionid=1&days=120&count=10

If I remove this for loop, everything renders correctly, except I'm stuck with `<object>` flash video; Windows 8 API only supports HTML5 video. So I need to convert them to iFrames.

Comment: Please paste the for loop into your question. Remember that most people here have busy lives and jobs just like you. Make it easier for people to analyze the problem.

Comment: Before my earlier edit, I had the loop up. Was making changes to the post when you were viewing.

Answer (score 1):

`element.getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList` which is *[live](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1590626202)*.

So, access object element from `objectPoll` by specifying index is not a good idea.

```
j objectPoll                   objectPoll[j]  (expected)
- ---------------------------- -------------  ---------
0 object#0, object#1, object#2 object#0       object#0
1 object#1, object#2           object#2       object#1
2 object#1                     `undefined`    object#2
```

Comment: This sheds some light on the problem; thank you. This is my first time programming via Javascript/HTML. 

I'll have to figure out an alternative method then.

Comment: I'm trying to run through all the objects and add a tag ID to each; IE: `objectPoll = htmlArticleContent.querySelectorAll("object")'

`for (var r = 0; r < numberOfObjects; r += 1) {
                    objectPoll[r].setAttribute("id","video"+r)
                }`

Then afterwards:

`for (var j = 0; j < numberOfObjects; j += 1) {
                    var currentObject = htmlArticleContent.getElementById("video"+j);
currentObject.replaceNode(document.createElement("button"));`

Running into the same problem.